# DoCmd.OpenQuery("Actionable Query") "Property Not Found"

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a code that executes `DoCmd.OpenQuery` Command and it that has been executing fine from last 3 years.

However, all of a sudden it has started failing with Error Message "Property Not Found". It randomly fails for anyone query from set of 5 queries. Further, it displays a message "Operation not allowed this time" if I try to execute the statement again.

These are Action Queries (Inserting data into SQL Server Linked Table),
within this query data is being inserted into SQL Server Linked table from SmartSheet Linked Table. I am surprised to see `DoCmd.OpenQuery` executes fine at one instance and fails at same statement at other instance. For your information I got the same error message when I tried to executed `DoCmd.RunSQL`.

Nothing has changed in ACCESS or in SQL Server.

E.g. Query

```
INSERT INTO dbo_SQL_Server_LinkedTable
SELECT Quarter,Site,Category, 'Commit',Comments
FROM Dbo_SmartSheet_LinkedTable;
```

Also, Just to mention that same set up works fine on Office 2016 32 bit. I cannot use this because Client Machine does not have Office 2016.

Thank you,
Irfan Khan

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: I tried to execute same set up on other Remote Machines and received same error message. This made me investigate the source and destination of the query and found problem with SQL Server. As per Admin team some packets were getting dropped from the connection. They made some changes and it is working fine now. Thank you